# handling 'NoneType' in Python regex

Tags: python

I am trying to create a uniform firewall document using python and regex, string looks like this:

```
config '''firewall address
    edit "FABRIC_DEVICE"
        set uuid ccac8fce-7f2b-51ea-c7fe-a3fb6d39974f
        set comment "IPv4 addresses of Fabric Devices."
    next
    edit "none"
        set uuid 1d740d84-7f17-51ea-e028-0814802b19ec
        set subnet 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255
    next
    edit "SSLVPN_TUNNEL_ADDR1"
        set uuid 1dcb40ae-7f17-51ea-bef5-f1056feda3e9
        set type iprange
        set associated-interface "ssl.VPN_Traffic"
        set start-ip x.x.x.x
        set end-ip x.x.x.x '''
```

I divided them into a list then individual string and then running the regex to pull the info

Now when I try to pull info on the string for type: `re.search('type\s(?P<type>.+)', fw_add`

I get the result for `fw_add[2]`, but since type is not present on `fw_add[0]` or `fw_add'[1]`, it throws an error

```
:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

How can I handle this, if it returns Nonetype?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I ended up using try/except...seems to be working well.

Comment: Would you provide the actual code? How are you capturing `re.search('type\s(?P<type>.+)', ...` ? Any rate, the result of `re.search` is NoneType when nothing is found, so all you'd need to do is check that *before* using `.group`, i.e. `r=re.search(...` and then `if r: ...`

Comment: There are two ways, generally, explicitly check if it is None before trying to access `.group`  or use exception handling... This doesn't really have anything to do with regex

Comment: **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].**

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to check explicitly for None than catching an exception that could happen for other reasons. I generaly use a simple test like the following, given that 'None' act like 'False' in a if/else statement and anything else act like True.

```
match=re.search('type\s(?P<type>.+)', fw_add)
if match:
   gr=match.group()
```